# Table ID in PHP

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to assign anID to the table I'm generating with PHP but it keeps returning an error. Here is the full code that works fine so far. All I want is to add an 'id' to the table so I can apply css styles to it in the relevant sheet

```
        <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","<un>","<pw>","monitor");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM presnationalresults ORDER BY Percentage DESC");

        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>President</th>
        <th>Party</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
        <th>Percentage</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['PresidentName'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['PartyCode'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['Votes'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['Percentage'] . "</td>";
          }
        echo "</table>";

        mysqli_close($con);
```

Any help? maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the exact error?

Comment: Any more MySQL code in there?

Comment: Why bother using `echo` to output static HTML? All you're doing is making it hard to get your quotes right.

Comment: Sorry. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\www.Elections.Mw\Elections.php on line 140". Line 140 is the line saying "<tr>"

Comment: And you think that `<tr>` is a valid piece of php code?

Comment: @user3013069 - `<tr>` is not valid PHP. You either need to close PHP before it (after your echo statement) or you need to echo `<tr>` as well.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being an inherent programming savant but I am trying to learn here. Editted my post with the full working code.

Comment: All I wanted was to add the 'id' to the tabl but everyway I try, I get some sort of error.

Comment: Dude, what is the error?!!!!

Comment: This is `Elections.php` where your getting parse error. can you please show 140th line of code. and another thing you want to add table id dynamically or only one table id

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm not being very clear I think. There is no error in the above file. All I wanted was the correct way to apply an id to the table. After messing around a bit I figured it out.

Comment: echo "<table id=\"election_tables\" border='1'>

Comment: Now I can atually do what 'm good at and apply all the CSS I can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below block of code . I have added table id and also close `</tr>` inside while loop

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "<un>", "<pw>", "monitor");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM presnationalresults ORDER BY Percentage DESC");

echo "<table border='1' id='table-id'>
        <tr>
        <th>President</th>
        <th>Party</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
        <th>Percentage</th>
        </tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PresidentName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PartyCode'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Votes'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Percentage'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; // you forget close tr
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```